# which parser to use for xml in java in combination with Jtree?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax, jdom

I have an XML file and i need to show it as a tree structure. The tree needs to be edited, searched for entries, etc and at the end XML format needs to be output.

My question is:

Which parser can be used to achieve this? Do all of the Parser can be visualized as JTree after it is parsed? have no experience with tree model in Java.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tutorial to build the JTree you want, but it doesn't contain the editing and searching part. It uses SAX parser.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/AsimpleXMLparserthatbuildsatreefromSAXevents.htm